# More specific variable types

Tags: r, memory

I'm dealing with large data tables and memory usage is a constraint. Within it, there are a lot of numeric columns that contain 1 or 2 digit numbers, but the memory allocated to them is huge. Is there a way of declaring a numeric such that it only takes up (for example) 8 bits per entry?

Comment: You could perhaps look into `raw vectors`

Comment: Import them as characters? The main question for whichever solution allows you to import it will be: can you use these numbers for the next step then?